# Bioinformatics widget

Tags: orange, bioinformatics

Why is there are no Volcano-plot or MA-plot in bioinformatics widget?

[image]

Comment: In Orange software。

Answer (score 1):

Volcano-plot and MA-plot are graphical methods. MA-plot of what? Everything in your screenshot is bioinformatics analysis. The plots are part of the analysis but not the name of the analysis itself.